# Angular2 + Angular1 + ES5 syntax component subscription

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all let me say I am still using ES5, mostly because I am writing this for a frontend of a Google Apps Scripts application and didn't have the time/patience to make TypeScript work.

I am currently using this method in order to upgrade my  Angular1 app to Angular2:

http://www.codelord.net/2016/01/07/adding-the-first-angular-2-service-to-your-angular-1-app/

I have a overlayLoaderService service to show a loading spinner in an overlay div with simple functions to get and set the loading state, and a overlayLoader component to show the div itself.

**Service:**

```js
var overlayLoaderService = ng.core.
  Injectable().
  Class({
    constructor: function() {
      this.loading = false;
      this.stateChange = new ng.core.EventEmitter();
    },
    setState: function(state) {
      this.loading.value = state;
      this.stateChange.emit(state);
    },
    getState: function() {
      console.log(this.loading);
    }
  });

upgradeAdapter.addProvider(overlayLoaderService);
angular.module('Gojira').factory('overlayLoaderService', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(overlayLoaderService));
```

**Component:**

```js
var OverlayLoaderComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'overlay-loader',
    template: '<div [hidden]="loading" id="overlay-loader"></div>',
    providers: [overlayLoaderService]
  }).Class({
    constructor: [overlayLoaderService, function(overlayLoaderService) {
      this.loading = !overlayLoaderService.loading.value;
      this._subscription = overlayLoaderService.stateChange.subscribe(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.loading = !value;
      });
    }],
  });

angular.module('Gojira').directive('overlayLoader', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(OverlayLoaderComponent));
```

What I am trying to do is to achieve is the component to update its `loading` property when I call setState() method in the overlayLoaderService.

The subscription is never called, so I guess I am doing something terribly wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is setState method called by Angular 1 component?

Comment: @sdfacre it is called by an Angular 1 controller.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
providers: [overlayLoaderService]
```

from OverlayLoaderComponent should work, as the provider has already been added to the adapter. Otherwise, it seems like angular 1 component and angular 2 component are using different instance of that service.

Comment: That is what I thought. The upgrade adapter must be what is messing all up.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I guess the upgradeAdapter is somehow creating a different instance of the service. Although it is a bit weird since I can access the same properties both from the A2 component and the A1 controller.

Comment: that's weird because I tried that and it worked for me. You didn't bootstrap angular 2 separately, did you? could you please provide more code, i.e. ng1 controller and the bootstrap part of code, or a plunker?

Comment: I am currently on a trip, let me get back home and tomorrow I will post you the complete code. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, this is so weird, because I just put it all on a pen for you to check it, and it works there...

http://codepen.io/kiroushi/pen/adMLJb

I need to troubleshoot it because my mind is playing tricks on me...

Comment: I guess the issue is still on the trip. haha